# How to reverse username in template tag i.e <a href=" "> in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

So, what I want is to be able to reverse the user to the profile page when he clicks the tag.
I've tried :

```
 href="{% url 'profile/' <username>  %}
 href="{% url 'profile/' signups.username  %}
```

but, I'm getting TemplateSyntaxError.

Comment: What is the `urls.py` for the profile page? You need to use the *name* of the view, not the URL part.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem, in django documentation 2.0 the name attribute isn't there and for this I could think anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add context variable or add with argument name

like this

```
href="{% url 'profile' signups.username  %}
```

or this

```
href="{% url 'profile' username=signups.username  %}
```

Also, you have to use your url name, not your url path. For this example, you should have your url with name `profile`. like below

```
path('profile/<str:username>/', your_view, name='profile')
```

Comment: ahh.. finally did the job. Thanks, I searched for it in the django documentation, but could find anything.

Comment: glad to solved! django 2.0 changed much about urls - so it's little bit weird when searching for urls. But just remember you should call your url namespace and name in template.

Comment: seriously, I was too confused.  I was searching for this everywhere since URL routing is one of the most important thing in django.

Comment: Right. It's important thing, and it's easy when use just few time - django's URL routing is really great I think. I recommend you to make namespace for each app - it's really good to distinguish. Also make your url name for RESTful. ie) if you make profile app - your url namespace will be `profile` and your url name will be `list`, `detail`, `create` and so on. Then you simply call like this `{% url 'profile:list' %}` or in your case, `{% url 'profile:detail' username=signups.username %}`. It's bit clear way

Comment: I'm pretty new in django and python. I would love to have you as a mentor and to be connected in social medias for furthur conversations. :-)

Comment: Oh sure why not! I love django and python and always want to make conversation about it.

Comment: so, how can I contact you?

Comment: um just give me your sns like fb or slack. or twitter? which one do you prefer?

Comment: ok I found you! just remove or hide your id for the security